# UIWebView delegate setup in @interface

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiwebview

My app has UIWebView that loads a document with links. I would like to be able to detect when the user clicks on a link.

Different places suggested changing the @interface in the delegate to be

```
  @interface MailComposerAppDelegate : UIViewController<UIwebViewDelegate>
```

Currently my @interface is

```
   @interface MailComposerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Changing to the UIwebViewDelegate makes Xcode complain that no protocol is defined.

I am not sure what the problem and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conform to multiple protocols. Try this:

```
@interface MailComposerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Then implement the appropriate methods for the new protocol, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple delegates by separating them with a comma, like this:

```
@interface MailComposerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Then you can implement UIWebViewDelegate methods.

Doing this will work but you really shouldn't be putting this into your Application Delegate class. You probably should read up a little on Cocoa/Objective-C programming.